# assigning scores for dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I require some assistance with computing scores to dictionary values.

Consider the following dictionary where keys are player-id's (integers from 1,2...N) and values are lists of rankings (i.e. the distinct integers from 1,2,...,N in some permutation). Example for N=4:

```
player = {1: [4, 2, 1, 3], 2: [4, 3, 1, 2], 3: [4, 3, 1, 2], 4: [1, 3, 4, 2], 5: [2, 3, 4, 1], 6: [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

I have used the following code to assign the desired scores, `y[i]` which can be seen below:

```
y = {}

for val in player.values():
    allValues = list(val)
    uniqueRank = set(allValues)

for i in uniqueRank:
    z = 0
    for value in player.values():
        if i == value[-1]:
            z += 0
        elif i == value[0]:
            z+= 3
        elif i  == value[1]:
            z+= 2
        elif i  == value[2]:
            z+= 1

    y[i] = z

print(y)
```

This then gives me the following scores, which are correct and what I desired:

```
{1: 8, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 11}
```

However, I want to simplify this code, automate the assignment of values to z instead of the `if..elif` clauses:

```
elif i  == value[1]:
    z+= 2
```

for example.

EDIT: The component for

```
for val in player.values():
    allValues = list(val)
    uniqueRank = set(allValues)
```

simply grabs the unique values from the dictionary above, so in this regard it simply collects 1-4, which is what the players are denoted by.

Comment: It's hard to understand from your description what your code is doing: compute some sum of rankings, or something. You have to show the vaue of `player.values()`, we can't follow the `for val in player.values(): ... allValues = list(val) ... range = set(allValues)` part. Also, `range` is a builtin, don't reassign, call that variable something else.

Comment: Also, your title is confusing: dictionaries don't have an 'index', unlike a list. Can you fix your title? dictionaries have keys and values. Seems like your 'values' for each key is a ranked list, which you then want to vo convert to weights. And are you aware that `i == value[-1]:` is testing the *last* element in `value`?

Comment: Yes, I == value[-1]: is in place to always assign the last value with 0. I will deal with all the other things now thanks :)

Comment: Is it given each 'value' is a list of length 4? If not, some solutions will fail.

Comment: what would you advise to foolproof if the length would be greater than 4?

Comment: ..and also that 'values' always contains the integers 1..4 in some permutation? (can there be duplicates? could 0, 5, 6 etc. appear?) Edit the question to show us a second example of length >=5 and we'll give you a more robust solution.

Comment: To avoid people downvoting; I recommend you edit the question to add explanation. What is the meaning behind the keys `i` and `values`. Are they player-numbers? rankings of players?

Comment: ok will edit and post when arranged. The values could be any value from 1 onwards, so it could be 1..4(in this case) or 1...100 in others. I used the whole set(allValues) thingy to eliminate duplicates, not sure if it was the best but still learning as you can see.

Comment: What do the values mean? rankings of player-numbers? or something else. Can they contain duplicates? other integers like 0,5,6? What is the significance of them being length-4? Help us help you...

Comment: This is just an example like explained, the values are indeed the ranking of player-numbers, they cannot contain duplicated (like said previously) and can be other integers, they were simply length1-4 as an example.

Comment: Then if all the 'values' lists are guaranteed to all have the same length (call it N), just parameterize the constant '3' (N-1) in the solutions given. But please edit the question text to improve it, don't leave important clarifications buried down here in the comments.

Comment: As to the ambiguous *"make this code more efficient"* (which usually refers to runtime, memory, big-O complexity). I think instead you meant *"simplify this code, automate the assignment of values to z instead of the `if..elif` clauses."* (If that isn't what you meant, please edit your question.) Simple code is desirable, even if isn't more 'efficient' in the strict sense. So don't say 'efficient', say 'simplify my code'.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up with terminology, I’ll make sure to edit with these points in mind for anyone with a similar issue in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the second loop a bit concisely if you replace

```
if i == value[-1]:
    z += 0
elif i == value[0]:
    z+= 3
elif i  == value[1]:
    z+= 2
elif i  == value[2]:
    z+= 1
```

with

```
for j, val in enumerate(value):
    if val == i:
        z += 3-j
```

The whole code as a dict comprehension:

```
y = {i: sum((3-j for value in player.values() for j, val in enumerate(value) if val == i)) for i in set([v for value in player.values() for v in value])}
```

Output:

```
{1: 8, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 11}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that which you can notice is the sum of the value with which you're incrementing `z` and the index of `i` add up to **3**. Thus instead of `if-elif`s you can just subtract the index of `i` in value and add it to `z`.

Also, I noticed that the 1st `for` loop which sets the `range` only assigns the last value in the player dictionary, but still it ran correct since only the 4 values (1,2,3,4) were being repeated, thus I slightly modified the code a little bit, like this...

```py
player = {1: [4, 2, 1, 3], 2: [4, 3, 1, 2], 3: [4, 3, 1, 2], 4: [1, 3, 4, 2], 5: [2, 3, 4, 1], 6: [2, 1, 3, 4]}

y, setAllValues = {}, set([val for lstval in player.values() for val in lstval])

for i in setAllValues:
    z = 0

    for value in player.values():
        z += (3 - value.index(i))

    y[i] = z

print(y)
```

Output:-

```
{1: 8, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 11}

Executed in 4.9591064453125e-05 seconds
```